# PHP page doesn't display downloaded PNG files

Tags: php, image, png

I am using QRICKIT (qrickit.com) to generate QR codes.  Instead of generating codes every time the page refreshes, I want to download them and use the ones already generated.

So, within the loop that iterates through my database table, I do this:

```
                $qrcodebase = "https://qrickit.com/api/qr.php?d=";
                $filename = "./product_images/" . $row["itemID"] . "_QR.png";
                if (!(file_exists($filename))) {
                    $url = $qrcodebase . $myurl . $brandpage . "/?itemID=" . $row["itemID"];
                    file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url));
                }
                echo "<td><img src=\"" . $filename . "\" height=60 width=60></td>";
```

When this executes, it generates the right HTML to display the image, and when I FTP to the product_images folder, the QR codes are there.  When I download the QR codes and open them up in an image editor, they open just fine.  But, when the web page displays, I get an X in a box that indicates a bad image.  Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Rather than all this complexity, why not just render QR codes locally with something like https://github.com/endroid/qr-code ?

Comment: It's run on a hosted Linux web server, I have FTP access to upload/download/delete from webroot, but not to build code and run it.

Comment: Actually, 3 lines of code is not complex...